# Initializing fanout for mint multiple times

Tags: solana, metaplex

We're building a frontend for [Hydra Wallet](https://hydra-docs.glasseaters.xyz) to help with wallet creation and management. One issue we ran into is understanding the edge cases of membership models other than the Wallet membership model as well as how the wallet works with tokens.

Let's say we create a wallet:

```ts
  const { fanout } = await fanoutSdk.initializeFanout({
    name: `Test@${Date.now()}`,
    membershipModel: MembershipModel.Wallet,
    totalShares: 100,
  });
```

After that, we initialize the wallet for accepting certain SPL tokens, *multiple times* with *different tokens*:

```ts
await fanoutSdk.initializeFanoutForMint({ fanout, mint1 });
await fanoutSdk.initializeFanoutForMint({ fanout, mint2 });
await fanoutSdk.initializeFanoutForMint({ fanout, mint3 });
```

- Will the fanout wallet accept all three types of tokens or just the last one?
- What happens if, let's say, there were already tokens of the first type owned by the wallet when the second call was made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think - I am not 100% sure though - that you should be able to use it with all three mints that you initialised.

The initialisation creates the necessary accounts for it to work. When distributing you will obviously have to run the call for each token.

To be save you should test this in devnet though. It’s done quite fast since you can just create and mint three different random spl tokens.